# Moving the contents of a directory to another directory (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsfilemanager

When a user uses my app without logging on I store all the files they create in a directory called default_dir(which contains files and sub-dirs). When they do eventually login in I need to move the files from default_dir to a newly created dir called user_name.

That gives me 2 options.

Rename default_dir to user_name (I can't see anything on NSFilemanager to indicate this is possible).

Or try to somehow copy all the files and dirs into a newly created dir, user_name.

Can you advise how best to proceed in accomplishing this please?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try NSFileManager's -moveItemAtURL:toURL:error: ?

Comment: Iterating through the item of the initial folder using this method should solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah.  And while I haven't actually tried it, I would think that renaming default_dir to user_name could be done with a single call to -moveItemAtURL:...

Comment: You think moveItemAtURL would allow me to rename the folder? I experiment in the morning and see whats happens. Will report back with results.